# Open contact group on Mac

Tags: applescript, contacts

I just want to use AppleScript to open an existing group in Mac Address Book (v7.1).

```
tell application "Contacts"
    set selected of group "friend" to true
    activate
end tell
```

above is the sample code for what I want.

Comment: **I just updated the code for what I want, it's workable for Mac Address Book (v7.1) now.**

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't the best Applescript code ever written but it did work for me to list the people in a specific group (on 10.8 mountain lion).

```
tell application "Contacts"
    activate
    set grp to first group where (name = "friend")
    tell grp
        get people
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: tell application "Contacts"
 set selected of group "Name of Group" to true
 activate
 tell application "System Events" to keystroke (key code 99)
end tell

Answer (score 0):

Above script works only if the group with name 'friend' actually exists. Otherwise the statement 'set grp to first...' fails. Thus it is safer to write

```
tell application "Contacts"
  activate
  if group "friend" exists then
    set grp to first group where (name = "friend")
    tell grp
      get people
    end tell
  end if
end tell
```